# One of the groups not showing when using combined legend on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot 3 models over 2 plots, but the plots only have 1 model in common (model A). However, when I try to make a combined plot, it doesn't show all 3 models. I'm looking for a way for the legend to have all 3 models (A,B,C).

**Code:**

```
cols=c("red","blue","green")
df = rbind(data.frame(model ="A",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)),
  data.frame(model ="B",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)))

plot<-ggplot()+
      geom_point(df, mapping=aes(x=x, y=val, group=model, color=model,size=2),size=2)+scale_x_reverse(limits = c(10,0))+
      geom_line(df, mapping=aes(x=x, y=val, group=model, color=model,size=1),size=1)+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
      labs(y = "y axis", x="x axis",color="Model")+ theme_bw() +theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +scale_color_manual(labels = c("A","B","C"),
         values = c(cols[1],cols[2],cols[3]))

gdf = rbind(data.frame(model ="A",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)),
  data.frame(model ="C",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)))

gplot<-ggplot()+
      geom_point(gdf, mapping=aes(x=x, y=val, group=model, color=model,size=2),size=2)+scale_x_reverse(limits = c(10,0))+
      geom_line(gdf, mapping=aes(x=x, y=val, group=model, color=model,size=1),size=1)+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
      labs(y = "y axis", x="x axis",color="Model")+ theme_bw() +theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +scale_color_manual(labels = c("A","C","B"),
         values = c(cols[1],cols[3],cols[2]))
final_plot = ggarrange(plot,gplot,
                       nrow=1,ncol=2,common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")
```

**Plot:**
[image]

**Latest attempt:** I've tried to combine the data into one dataset and then subset, but I get the same result

```
cols=c("red","blue","green")
df = rbind(data.frame(model ="A",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)),
  data.frame(model ="B",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)), data.frame(model ="C",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)),
  data.frame(model ="A",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)))
df$ind=1
df$ind[21:40]=0

plot<-ggplot(df)+
      geom_point(data=df%>%subset(ind==1), mapping=aes(x=x, y=val, group=model, color=model,size=2),size=2)+scale_x_reverse(limits = c(10,0))+
      geom_line(data=df%>%subset(ind==1), mapping=aes(x=x, y=val, group=model, color=model,size=1),size=1)+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
      labs(y = "y axis", x="x axis",color="Model")+ theme_bw() +theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +scale_color_manual(labels = c("A","B","C"),
         values = c(cols[1],cols[2],cols[3]))

gplot<-ggplot(df)+
      geom_point(data=df%>%subset(ind==0), mapping=aes(x=x, y=val, group=model, color=model,size=2),size=2)+scale_x_reverse(limits = c(10,0))+
      geom_line(data=df%>%subset(ind==0), mapping=aes(x=x, y=val, group=model, color=model,size=1),size=1)+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
      labs(y = "y axis", x="x axis",color="Model")+ theme_bw() +theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +scale_color_manual(labels = c("A","C","B"),
         values = c(cols[1],cols[3],cols[2]))

final_plot = ggarrange(plot,gplot,
                       nrow=1,ncol=2,common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")
```

Comment: I would consider using `facet_wrap()` instead of ggarrange - there's nothing in the provided example that suggests it wouldn't be just as good for your purposes and would do this quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the suggestion by Paul:

```
cols=c("red","blue","green")
df = rbind(data.frame(model ="A",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)),
  data.frame(model ="B",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)), data.frame(model ="C",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)),
  data.frame(model ="A",x=10:1,val=runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)))
df$ind=1
df$ind[21:40]=0

plot<-ggplot(df)+
      geom_point(data=df, mapping=aes(x=x, y=val, group=model, color=model,size=2),size=2)+scale_x_reverse(limits = c(10,0))+
      geom_line(data=df, mapping=aes(x=x, y=val, group=model, color=model,size=1),size=1)+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
      labs(y = "y axis", x="x axis",color="Model")+ theme_bw() +theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +scale_color_manual(labels = c("A","B","C"),
         values = c(cols[1],cols[2],cols[3]))+facet_wrap(~ ind)
```

[image]

Comment: Well done! If you don't mind to accept your own answer once you are able to, so this question will not flag as unanswered any longer. Much appreciated!